# Pass a String from one .m to another .m

Tags: objective-c

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "MyFirstAnnotation.h"


@implementation MainViewController


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)annosetzen:(id)sender{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coor;
    coor.latitude = 54.3327162876622;
    coor.longitude = 10.1518177986145;

    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.01;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.01;
    MKCoordinateRegion region;

    region.center = coor; 
    region.span = span; 

    MyFirstAnnotation *anno = [[MyFirstAnnotation alloc]init]; 
    [mapView addAnnotation:anno];

    [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];

    //MKReverseGeocoder *revGeo = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:coor];
    //revGeo.delegate = self; 
    //[revGeo start];   
}
```

Next .m which has to get the string

```
#import "MyFirstAnnotation.h"

@implementation MyFirstAnnotation
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate { 
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coor; 
    coor.latitude = 54.3327162876622; 
    coor.longitude = 10.1518177986145; 
    return coor;
}
- (NSString *)title {
    return theTitle;
}
- (NSString *)subtitle {
    return theSubTitle;
}
```

the Title and theSubTitle are Strings and have to be passed from the MainViewController .m to be use in the MyFirstAnnotation .m

Do you have a easy example how to do this? Im realy long searching for this easy step but I dosnt find the answer :-(

Please help me

Comment: You could add it to the parent class or delegate and then reference it from your implementation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass a String from one .m to another .m file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451172/how-to-pass-a-string-from-one-m-to-another-m-file). Please edit your questions if necessary rather than posting essentially the same thing multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do this?

```
 MyFirstAnnotation *anno = [[MyFirstAnnotation alloc] init];
 NSString *one = [anno title];     
 NSString *two = [anno subtitle];
```

edit: to set strings FROM first file TO second you should add setters methods to

`MyFirstAnnotation.h`

```
//...

- (void)setTitle:(NSString*)title;

//...

- (void)setSubTitle:(NSString*)subTitle {
```

`MyFirstAnnotation.m`

```
//...

- (void)setTitle:(NSString*)title {
    theTitle = [title copy];
}


//...

- (void)setSubTitle:(NSString*)subTitle {
    theSubTitle = [subTitle copy];
}
```

And then call them from main file:

```
// ....
MyFirstAnnotation *anno = [[MyFirstAnnotation alloc]init];
[anno setTitle:@"qwertt"];
[anno setSubTitle:@"asdfg"];
// ....
```